# Efficiently find order statistics of unsorted list prefixes?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, language-agnostic

`A` is an array of the integers from `1` to `n` in random order.

I need random access to the `i`th largest element of the first `j` elements in at least log time.

What I've come up with so far is an `n x n` matrix `M`, where the element in the `(i, j)` position is the `i`th largest of the first `j`. This gives me constant-time random access, but requires `n^2` storage.

By construction, `M` is sorted by row and column. Further, each column differs from its neighbors by a single value.

Can anyone suggest a way to compress `M` down to `n log(n)` space or better, with `log(n)` or better random access time?

Comment: can give a sample input and output?

Comment: This is a really fun question, I'm thinking about it :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe you can perform the access in O(log(N)) time, given O(N log(N)) preprocessing time and O(N log(N)) extra space.  Here's how.

You can augment a red-black tree to support a `select(i)` operation which retrieves the element at rank `i` in O(log(N)) time.  For example, [see this PDF](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall07/Lectures/augtrees.pdf) or the appropriate chapter of *Introduction to Algorithms*.

You can implement a red-black tree (even one augmented to support `select(i)`) in a functional manner, such that the insert operation returns a new tree which shares all but O(log(N)) nodes with the old tree.  See for example [*Purely Functional Data Structures*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521663504) by Chris Okasaki.

We will build an array `T` of purely functional augmented red-black trees, such that the tree `T[j]` stores the indexes `0 ... j-1` of the first `j` elements of `A` sorted largest to smallest.

Base case: At `T[0]` create an augmented red-black tree with just one node, whose data is the number 0, which is the index of the 0th largest element in the first 1 elements of your array `A`.

Inductive step: For each `j` from 1 to `N-1`, at `T[j]` create an augmented red-black tree by purely functionally inserting a new node with index `j` into the tree `T[j-1]`.  This creates at most O(log(j)) new nodes; the remaining nodes are shared with `T[j-1]`.  This takes  O(log(j)) time.

The total time to construct the array `T` is O(N log(N)) and the total space used is also O(N log(N)).

Once `T[j-1]` is created, you can access the `i`th largest element of the first `j` elements of `A` by performing `T[j-1].select(i)`.  This takes O(log(j)) time.  Note that you can create `T[j-1]` lazily the first time it is needed.  If `A` is very large and `j` is always relatively small, this will save a lot of time and space.

Comment: I just thought of this solution and was going to post it here, but you beat me to it.  Excellent answer!

Answer (score 3):

Unless I misunderstand, you are just finding the [k-th order statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic) of an array which is the prefix of another array.

This can be done using an algorithm that I think is called 'quickselect' or something along those lines. Basically, it's like quicksort:

1. Take a random pivot
2. Swap around array elements so all the smaller ones are on one side
3. You know this is the p+1th largest element where p is the number of smaller array elements
4. If p+1 = k, it's the solution! If p+1 > k, repeat on the 'smaller' subarray. If p+1 < k, repeat on the larger 'subarray'.

There's a (much) better description [here](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/161/960125.html) under the Quickselect and Quicker Select headings, and also just generally on the internet if you search for k-th order quicksort solutions.

Although the worst-case time for this algorithm is O(n2) like quicksort, its expected case is much better (also like quicksort) if you properly select your random pivots. I think the space complexity would just be O(n); you can just make one copy of your prefix to muck up the ordering for.

Comment: It looks like you'd need separate `O(j)` space for each separate `j`, totaling quadratic space.  If you can find a way to combine that, then you're onto something.

Comment: Hm right. The setup and teardown of the spare array would be O(n), so that could be included in the time complexity and you would never need more than O(j) memory complexity at the same time.